# How to send a Variable to Netmiko send command

Tags: python, netmiko

I am trying to run a python script to get a input from the user for the cisco switch interface ID ex: Gi1/0/1 and feed that into the script(show interface  and send the command to cisco switch.

I know the input() function will take the input while executing the script but what I don't know is how to take that input and merge it with "show" command

Can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How about sharing the code you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script that checking 'show interface xxx'

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler 
cisco = { 
 'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 
 'host': 'cisco.domain.com', 
 'username': 'admin', 
 'password': 'cisco123', 
 } 

try:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
    net_connect.enable()
    interface =input('Pls enter the interface name: ')
    output = net_connect.send_command("show interface " + interface)
    print('*'*10)
    print(output)
    net_connect.disconnect()
except:
    print(cisco['host']+' not connected!')
```

As you can see it is pretty simple. basically we are sending a string inside of `.send_command()`. So you can put what ever string you want to send as below:

```
interface = input('Pls enter the interface name: ')
output = net_connect.send_command("show interface " + interface)
```